# Second call to mysql procedure generates 1172 error multiple rows returned

Tags: mysql, database

I'm creating a procedure to retrieve someones password from the DB on login. Calling the procedure works fine on first call but on the second call if the user enters incorrect details or does not exist in the system I get a MySql error 1172 saying multiple rows are being returned from the query.
I've made sure that the "users" table has a unique Email and Mobile field and the "users_login_attempts" field also has a unique username field.
So I'm not sure where the multiple rows are coming from...

```
    IN Username VARCHAR(75),
    IN LoginIP VARBINARY(16),
    IN IPGeoLocation VARCHAR(30),
    OUT ReturnValue VARCHAR(350)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE UStatus BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE UStatusID TINYINT(1);
DECLARE UPwdHash VARBINARY(256);
DECLARE UAttempts TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE ULastAttempt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now();
DECLARE UErrorMsg VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT 'An error has occured!';

    # Check login attempts table to see if user is timed out or blocked
    IF EXISTS (SELECT Username FROM users_login_attempts WHERE ((Username = Username) AND ((Attempts = 5 AND DATE_ADD(LastAttempt, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) <= NOW()) OR Attempts = 7))) THEN
        # Set return error message
        SELECT Attempts INTO UAttempts FROM users_login_attempts WHERE Username = Username;
        SELECT LastAttempt INTO ULastAttempt FROM users_login_attempts WHERE Username = Username;

        IF (UAttempts = 5) THEN
            SET UStatus = 0;
            SET UErrorMsg = CONCAT('Due to multiple failed login attempts, we have temporarily locked your account. Please try to login again in ', "TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, DATE_ADD(ULastAttempt, INTERVAL 10 minutes, NOW()))", ' minutes.');
        ELSE
            SET UStatus = 0;
            SET UErrorMsg = 'Due to multiple failed login attempts. As a security precaution, your account has been locked.';
        END IF;

        # Set return value Output
        SELECT UStatus AS Status, UErrorMsg AS Error;
    ELSE
        # Query DB users table to see if user exists and get password hash
        IF EXISTS (SELECT Email FROM users WHERE (Email = Username OR Mobile = Username)) THEN
        # Get users status and set default error message
        SELECT StatusID INTO UStatusID FROM users WHERE (Email = Username OR Mobile = Username);
        SET UStatus = 0;
        SET UErrorMsg = 'Sorry user status not available!';
        SET UPwdHash = '';

        # Check users statusID
        # User account active
        IF (UStatusID = 1) THEN
            SELECT Password INTO UPwdHash FROM users WHERE (Email = Username OR Mobile = Username);
            SET UStatus = 1;
            SET UErrorMsg = '';
        END IF;

        # User account suspended
        IF (UStatusID = 2) THEN
            SET UStatus = 0;
            SET UErrorMsg = 'Your account has been temporarily suspended.';
        END IF;

        # User account Deactivated
        IF (UStatusID = 3) THEN
            SET UStatus = 0;
            SET UErrorMsg = 'Your account has been deactivated.';
        END IF;

        # User has not completed registration
        IF (ISNULL(UStatusID)) THEN
            SET UStatus = 0;
            SET UErrorMsg = 'Sorry before you can login you must complete registration of your account.';
        END IF;
        ELSE
            # User does not exist in DB Update login attempts tbl           
            SELECT Attempts INTO UAttempts FROM users_login_attempts WHERE (Username = Username);
            IF (UAttempts < 7 OR ISNULL(UAttempts)) THEN
                INSERT
                INTO users_login_attempts(
                    Username,
                    Attempts,
                    IPAddress,
                    IPGeoLocation)
                VALUES(
                    Username,
                    1,
                    LoginIP,
                    IPGeoLocation)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                    Attempts = VALUES(Attempts) +1,
                    IPAddress = VALUES(IPAddress),
                    IPGeoLocation = VALUES(IPGeoLocation);
            END IF;
            
            # create error message
            SET UStatus = 0;
            SET UErrorMsg = 'The supplied credentials were not valid!';
        END IF;


        # Set return value output
        SELECT UStatus AS Status, UPwdHash AS PwdHash, UErrorMsg AS Error;
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Please add the error message on full.

Comment: There's scope for ambiguity when you're selecting something `WHERE username = username`. I'd expect a query with a condition like that to return the entire table.

Comment: Avoid giving parameters the same names as table columns - as already commented mysql will compare the column name to itself.

Comment: This is a lot of clearly *application* code jammed into the DB.

Comment: There's no need to use two queries to assign two variables when the `WHERE` condition is the same. You can use `SELECT col1, col2 INTO var1, var2 ...`